# Indexing questions with array formulas in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I'm new to array formulas in Excel and my brain has been trained in R for too long, so I'm sorry if this question is simple or too specific. I have data that looks like this:

```
ID  Iteration   Value   Group1  Group2
2   1           100     0       0
2   2           85      1       0
2   3           28      0       0
3   1           94      1       0
5   1           83      0       1
5   2           50      1       1
6   1           94      0       0
6   2           28      1       0
```

I want to use array formulas to query the data in a few different ways. I want to:

1. For each ID, find the first iteration that has Group1 = 1.
2. For each ID, what is the maximum value when Group1 = 1.
3. For each ID, how many iterations of Group1 = 1 did it take to get to the maximum value when Group1 = 1.

I've figured out how to specify the maximum for each ID via: `{=MAX(IF(A:A=A2,C:C))}`

Any assistance would be appreciated. I've gone through a few quick tutorials so far, and I'm willing to look through any other good resources you may know of.

Comment: Text is preferred to image. It helps us to replicate your circumstances

Comment: Thank you to the kind person who converted to text. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this and tell me what you think - particularly for question 3

My setup looks like this

[image]

All formulas drag down and they are as follows:

**Formula in B14 (Question 1)**

```
{=INDEX($B$2:$B$9,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$9=A14)*($D$2:$D$9=1),0))}
```

**Formula in G14 (Question 2)**

```
{=MAX(($A$2:$A$9=$F14)*($D$2:$D$9=1)*$C$2:$C$9)}
```

**Formula in K14 (Question 3)**

```
{=SUM(($A$2:$A$9=J14)*($C$2:$C$9=G14)*$B$2:$B$9)}
```

---

**Update**

If you want to know how many times in ID=2 that Group1=1 before we reach the maximum we found for ID =2 in question 2, then I'd proceed like this:

Add another column to your data, I labeled it: *Group1 Passes*. Placing this in the new column, `F2`, and drag down.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$D$2:D2,1)
```

You can then use the following in `K14`

```
=SUM(($A$2:$A$9=J14)*($C$2:$C$9=G14)*($D$2:$D$9=1)*$F$2:$F$9)
```

Comment: This helps so much, you have no idea. Even just seeing how you attack the problem to come up with these formulas is hugely beneficial. I feel like I've learned a lot.

I don't believe your formula for question 3 (in K14) is correct. It is showing the total number of iterations to get to the max, not the number of Group1 iterations. (It just so happens that they're the same in this example.) But this has helped enormously, so I will try to solve this issue - I can see that at some point column D should be referenced.

Comment: The formula for question 3 needs one more condition to exclude cases where more than one cell has the maximum number. You can just add `*($D$2:$D$9=1)`
A good intro to Array formulas can be found here [Excel array formulas, functions and constants](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/02/25/array-formulas-functions-excel/#evaluate-formula)

Comment: Thanks for the link. That solution is counting the total number of iterations, not the number of Group1 iterations. I believe I made it work with `{=SUM(($A$2:$A$9=J14)*($D$2:$D$9=1)}`?

Comment: What if the maximum happens before the last group1=1 for a particular ID? For example, put a 1 in `D4`. I updated my answer for what I think might work

Comment: Thanks for everybody's input. I really feel like I've learned more about array formulas. This has been one of my more positive experiences on this board, so thanks for dealing with my ineptitude!

Comment: Always happy to help :)